# Validate text box to accept only small int

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to validate a text box to accept only small int (32767) ?

Comment: Did you try any code?? Show us what have you done to help you

Comment: Why not a simple if condition saying like `if(num <= 32767) { //Your code }` along with key events.

Comment: i have a function that accepts only numeric values only, now i need to verify whether the value is smallint (becoz in sql server the datatype for the specified value is SmallInt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in features of HTML:

```html
<input type="number" max="32767" />
```

On submit, the browser will stop the submission and provide an accurate message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

you must use use regular expression.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj6Xf/4/)

```
<script>
    function clean(e) {
        var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
        var regex = /[a-z]/gi;
        textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "");

    }
</script>
<textarea id="ta" name="ta" onkeyup="clean('ta')" onkeydown="clean('ta')"></textarea>
```

now what will this do is that it will replace all other character such as alphabet or other symbol and it will only allow to write number and if someone will try to write alphabet or other character then it will remove them

you should do some research of your own. this website should be the last option to get your answer

Comment: Regex is not the only option -- definitely not a must.

Comment: well yes i just adviced him

Comment: i have a function in onkeypress to accept only numeric values and it wont accept any other values.